# GWT validation i18n

Tags: validation, gwt, internationalization

I was hoping following might work:

```
@Size(min = 1, message = "{my.custom.message}")
private String name;
```

with ValidationMessages.properties in my source path, alogn with my other text resources:

```
my.custom.message=it is kinda short
```

...yet the constraint violation still reads `{my.custom.message}`

Does one have to do something special to have the ValidationMessages.properties file picked up? And where is this documented please?

Apparently it should work, somehow: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/5762

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [TBroyer's reply](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/5762#issuecomment-352167814) I managed to make it work in my project.

In a nutshell...

...define **MyCustomValidationMessages** interface:

```
public interface MyCustomValidationMessages extends com.google.gwt.i18n.client.ConstantsWithLookup {
    @DefaultStringValue("NotNull constraint violated")
    @Key("notNull")
    String notNull();

    @DefaultStringValue("Size constraint violated")
    @Key("size")
    String size();
}
```

...create **MyCustomValidationMessages.properties** right next to it:

```
notNull=must not be null
size=must be at least {min} characters long
```

...define **MyCustomValidationMessagesResolver** class and make it use messages from MyCustomValidationMessages interface:

```
public class MyCustomValidationMessagesResolver extends AbstractValidationMessageResolver
        implements UserValidationMessagesResolver {
    public MyCustomValidationMessagesResolver() {
        super(GWT.create(MyCustomValidationMessages.class));
    }
}
```

...in your **AmazingModule.gwt.xml** override use of UserValidationMessagesResolver with MyCustomValidationMessagesResolver:

```
<replace-with class="amazing.project.client.MyCustomValidationMessagesResolver">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.validation.client.UserValidationMessagesResolver"/>
</replace-with>
```

...apply the constraints in your DTO bean (note the curly brackets):

```
public class MyDto {
    @NotNull(message = "{notNull}")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "{size}")
    private String name;
}
```

Voilá!

[Working example is here.](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/samples/validation/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/validation/client/)

If you are sure you have done everything and it just does not work try deleting GWT's temp folders and restarting your IDE. Sometimes merely rebuilding your project and restarting the codeserver (in Idea) might not be enough. #PITA